# Qt Clipboard operation does not work in tests on OSX

Tags: python, macos, qt

I have a widget where the mac shortcut Command+C works well interactively, and the content is correctly stored in the clipboard.

I am trying to implement the same behavior in the unittests. It works on other platforms, but not on Mac.

```
    expected_clipboard = "whatever"
    self._widget.show()
    Test.processEvents()

    QtTest.QTest.keyClick(self._widget, QtCore.Qt.Key_C, QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier)
    Test.processEvents()

    current_clipboard= QtGui.qApp.clipboard().text()
    self.assertEqual(current_clipboard, expected_clipboard) # Fails.
```

According to the Qt documentation, ControlModifier is the proper corresponding entity for Command on Mac. I also tried MetaModifier just out of curiosity, but it doesn't work.

The action is correctly attached with the following code

```
       self._action = QtGui.QAction('text', self) 
       action.connect(self._action, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'), self.copyAction)
       self._action.setShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence.Copy)
       self.addAction(self._action)
```

Qt 4.8 latest, osx 10.8.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is that the window must be visible, raised and activated, otherwise OSX does not deliver events. Just call widget.raise_() and widget.activateWindow()